# Googleapis.com - What are the IPs and Ports for firewall?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

My organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or from the Internet, so i need the ip address and ports used by googleapis.com.

i want to access google cloud Speech-to-text api and dialogflow api

Comment: You can query Google's DNS server for the `CURRENT` IP addresses for any public endpoint. Google uses load balancers, proxies, etc. so nothing is static and you must be prepared for changes.

Answer (score 5):

You can get full list of IP addresses here
https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json

As far as I know its gets updated regularly and it covers all the IPs. However, this list is quite long.

Comment: And heres how to handle it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665531/how-to-find-googles-ip-address/70754702#70754702